# How to submit https form using C#

Tags: c#, .net, forms, https

I am creating a C#/.NET app to automatically reconnect to a wifi hotspot. The Internet access detection works fine but I can't reconnect. The wifi hotspot uses an HTTPS POST login form.

I tried several suggestions from stackoverflow but nothing worked so far: the answer I get from my request is the login page and I am not connected to the Internet.

I tried:

```
public class Hotspot
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public string Inputs { get; set; }

    public HttpStatusCode Connect()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.Url);
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        request.Method = this.Method;

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; });

        byte[] post_bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.Inputs);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = post_bytes.Length;
        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(post_bytes, 0, post_bytes.Length);
        }

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        return response.StatusCode;
    }

    public void Connect2()
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "text/xml");
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] response = client.UploadData(this.Url, "POST", encoding.GetBytes(this.Inputs));
            Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(response));
        }
    }
}
```

- this.Url looks like @"https://hotspot.somtehing.com/nb4_crypt.php"
- this.Method is "POST"
- this.Inputs is a string representing all of the inputs with their value (like @"username=me&password=something&conditions=on&blablah=")

Both method output the login page and I am still not connected to the Internet. The first method (Connect) returns 200.
I checked the input values and they're correct: I can connect using a web browser.

Comment: what does the browser outputs ?

Comment: The browser reopens the login page with a div that masks the page and stays for 8 seconds telling the login was successful and then redirect to the page I asked before.